# Pandas export data to CSV and make first row headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export

I have this table which i export to CSV Using this code:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype("datetime64").dt.date
df = df.set_index("time")
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.to_csv(r'C:\****\Exports\exportMMA.csv', index=False)
```

While exporting this, my result is:

| column1 | column2 | column3 |
|:----    |:------: | -----:  |
| FT1     | FT2     | FT3     |
| 12      | 8       | 3       |
I want to get rid of column 1,2,3 and replace the header with FT2 and FT3

Tried this :

```
new_header = df.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
df = df[1:] #take the data less the header row
df.columns = new_header #set the header row as the df header
```

And This :

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Somehow it wont work, I not really in need to replace the headers in the dataframe having the right headers in csv is more important.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try `df = df.iloc[1:]` and what exatly do you mean with "Somehow it wont work" what exactly is the problem. To state the obvious, you did the df transformation before using to_csv right? Can you provide samle data? e.g. `df.iloc[:5].to_dict()`

Comment: just export with an offset `df.iloc[1:].to_csv(r'C:\****\Exports\exportMMA.csv', index=False)`

Comment: I still need my index. When i use df.iloc[1:] it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the columns names in your DataFrame before writing it to a CSV file. Here is the updated code:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].astype("datetime64").dt.date
df = df.set_index("time")
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean'])
df = df.reset_index()

# Changing the column names
df.columns = ['FT2', 'FT3']

# Writing the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv(r'C:\****\Exports\exportMMA.csv', index=False, header=True)
```

The header parameter in the to_csv method determines whether or not to write the column names to the CSV file. In this case, it's set to True so that the column names will be written.

Comment: The problem is that i've more columns than in my example and in some cases they will be diffrent than here